# Does this need rephrasing? "Student Representative of the Coordinating Committee of the Bachelor's degree in Mathematics"

Tags: parts-of-speech

Student Representative of the Coordinating Committee of the Bachelor's degree in Mathematics.

This is a long sentence in a CV I'm having trouble with.

Does it sound ok or should it be rephrased?

Would "Student Representative in the Mathematics Bachelor's degree Coordinating Committee" sound better? Worse? Hogwash?

Comment: Is it really necessary to include ***Mathematics*** and ***Bachelor*** here? I'm guessing it's contextually obvious from the rest of your CV that you studied Mathematics (why else would you be on the Coordinating Committee?). And even though almost every hit I got by Googling "degree Coordinating Committee" explicitly said "**Master's** Degree", I don't think it would be serious misrepresentation if you ditched ***Bachelor***.

Comment: Hi FumbleFingers, so just: "Student Representative in the Coordinating Committee" ?

Comment: More usually one is *on* a committee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from questions about what is easiest to read or say, there is one difference between the two options that can change meaning. The first options has "... Representative **of** the ... Committee," and the second has "... Representative **in** the ... Committee." The first implies that the committee selected a person to represent the committee to other people, but I think you mean the second: that a representative was sent to be a part of the committee, and to represent students.

I agree with the suggestions that you can make it easier to read by replacing some proper nouns with common nouns. No one is likely to call your school and try to find the exact committee, by name, to verify your story. The point is that you were selected to represent students to a committee that coordinated a degree program. Something like this ought to be enough: "Student representative in a degree coordinating committee."